# How to save Animation Nodes cache without baking to mesh?

Tags: animation-nodes, cache

It seems like all caching data from `Subprogramm` is purged after closing a file, but can we re-use this internal cache?

I was thinking about running few instances of Blender to write `Subprogramm Loop` cache on different frames simultaneously and then save it for further use. Mainly to speed up the process, as AN doesn't use all CPU power.

P.S. Right now I am saving OBJ sequences splitted between two instances of Blender and converting it to Alembic, which is quite annoying.

**EDIT:** Trying to implement Omar's solution...

Cube is simply rotating at (0,0,0). I am caching vertices and writing them to dynamic keys. After disconnecting `Subprogram` from upper `Expression` I can keep data for 1 full animation timeline. When I want to repeat animation - all data is lost.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no built-in way to save cache persistently. However, for simple data types, you can store your cache in ID properties in objects. For instance, if you have a vector list `vecs` that you wish to save, you can save it in an object `obj` using the expression:

```
obj["frame_1"] = vecs
```

And retrieve the data using the expression `obj["frame_1"]`. You can change the key `frame_1` to anything to cache multiple data, per frame maybe. For example, if you wish to save the locations of vertices along frames, you could use the following node tree:

[image: Save]

If you now reopen your blend file and use the following node tree, you will get the data you saved:

[image: Get]

Comment: Could you please tell where should I place this part with expressions in the nodetree. I feel, like I'm doing it completely wrong.

Comment: @SergeL Added an example.

Comment: Thank you, but there is still a problem. As I said in edited question, data is stored only for one round of animation (from 1 to 250 it is OK, when it is time to repeat timeline - data is lost). And lost when you scrub timeline backwards.

Comment: @SergeL hmmm, I don't see why this would be the case. Does the data depend on anything other than the time?

Comment: Cube has driver (`frame/16`) on Z rotation. Nothing more and there is no other animation in the scene. Interesting thing, that if I reopen this .blend I can see data again but still only for one round.

Comment: @SergeL After you save the cache, you should remove the node tree that does the saving, this way your data don't get overwritten. Maybe used a script node with an if statement to see if data is already stored in that key and in that case, do nothing.

Comment: Yeah, that works! I thought unplugging Vector list would be enough, but I should unplug everything (instead of complete removing)