# Easier way to convert text to mesh for keyframe baking with animation nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

Below is the animation node set up for a timer that just alternates between 0s and 1s. I would like to bake keyframes for this animation so that I can render the entire animation on sheepit.
But apparently, '0 s' is a text and so I can't do it. Is there a way to make a simple modification to the node tree below or do I have to make an entirely new node tree to be able to bake the keyframes?
[image]

Comment: Apart from baking to keyframes (which is quite limited) you can store values in *Object ID properties*, but .blend file will become bigger. See here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130035/how-to-save-animation-nodes-cache-without-baking-to-mesh

Comment: You may just create two meshes and hide/show them in an alternating pattern. Would that work for you?

Comment: Yeah, I guess that would give the same effect. Thanks.